# NotFittedError: All estimators failed to fit while using CatBoostClassifier with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, catboost

I am trying to use GridSearchCV with CatBoostClassifier for multiclass (3), and am getting error. The code seems to work OK in [this Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/kevrchen/catboost-gridsearchcv-feature-engineering). The estimator also works successfully without GridSearchCV.

Here is the code and error:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier()
params = {'iterations': [500],
          'depth': [4, 5, 6],
          'loss_function': ['Logloss', 'CrossEntropy'],
          'l2_leaf_reg': np.logspace(-20, -19, 3),
          'leaf_estimation_iterations': [10],
          'eval_metric': ['Accuracy'],
          'use_best_model': ['True'],
          'logging_level':['Silent'],
          'random_seed': [42]
         }

scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)
clf_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=params, scoring=scorer, cv=10)
clf_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-d6ecb7a4f83f> in <module>
----> 1 clf_grid.fit(X_train, y_train,eval_set=(X_train,y_train))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    839                 return results
    840 
--> 841             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    842 
    843             # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1286     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1287         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1288         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1289 
   1290 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    825                 # of out will be done in `_insert_error_scores`.
    826                 if callable(self.scoring):
--> 827                     _insert_error_scores(out, self.error_score)
    828                 all_candidate_params.extend(candidate_params)
    829                 all_out.extend(out)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _insert_error_scores(results, error_score)
    295 
    296     if successful_score is None:
--> 297         raise NotFittedError("All estimators failed to fit")
    298 
    299     if isinstance(successful_score, dict):

NotFittedError: All estimators failed to fit
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Providing a minimal reproducible example would make this much easier to figure out.  Often a good first step is to set `error_score='raise'` to get an error traceback.  @UseR10085 if you can provide those in a new question (this one is a bit old), link to it from here.

Comment: @BenReiniger As you have suggested, I have created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74596455/notfittederror-all-estimators-failed-to-fit-for-randomizedsearchcv). Please see if you can help me out.